# AngularJs - Clear the entire text in a input textbox on pressing backspace button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

gone through the web posts but not enough luck to find a solution. My requirement is to clear the entire account number when the user (deletes the right most digit, 9 here, of the account number ex: 12345678**9** ) press backspace from end of the account number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ex: 12345678**9**. backspace press on **9** should clear the entire account from the input text box.

Comment: Seems like an odd UX requirement there.  What if you just wanted to remove the 9, meant to hit but hit 9 instead and it deletes everything?  As this seems to be a custom request you'd probably want something like a ng-click or create an event on the input.  Listen for the backspace key and check the to insure you're at the end of your input value and just clear it out.

Comment: I'd just recommend not to do this, as you'd have to create an event, 1 watcher, listen to the input another watcher, compare where you are and delete.  Not a good outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that it is not a good practice, but if you want to do this you can use $scope.$watch to track changes on input and compare new value of input with previous value.substring(0,length - 1)

```
  $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(oldValue != undefined && newValue != undefined){
        if(oldValue.substring(0, oldValue.length - 1) == newValue){
          $scope.data = "";
        }
    }
  });
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRT9Wug0D6OyjleuDvsN?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you all for throwing me great knowledge. based on my requirement I have picked up the watcher technique for now and explained the business that it may not be good idea for our purpose. Alternatively suggested selectOnFocus - which selects entire text on focus and the user can either clear whole text or modify as needs.

Comment: @Yespie I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes good sense in an app where you need to enter similar numbers fast (perhaps based on a default value) but also need to reset the input field quickly. Here is a small directive to do that :

```js
angular.module('myApp').directive('clearOnBackspace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var length = attrs.clearOnBackspace || 9;
      element.on('keydown', function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        if (key == 8 && element[0].value.length == length) element[0].value = ''
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" clear-on-backspace>  <!-- clear on 9th letter, the default -->
<input type="text" clear-on-backspace="5"> <!-- clear on 5th letter -->
```